# SQLite Update error: no such column: COLUMN_CHECKBOX (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

i am trying to update an SQLite database after filtering based on input data. below is my code

```
public void insert_checkbox(String Str1, String chkboxValue){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_CHECKBOX, Str1 );

        db.execSQL("UPDATE " + ResturantEntry.TABLE_NAME + " SET COLUMN_CHECKBOX = '" + Str1 + "' WHERE COLUMN_LOCATION = '" + chkboxValue + "'");
        this.getWritableDatabase().insertOrThrow(ResturantContract.ResturantEntry.TABLE_NAME,"",contentValues);


    }
}
```

my create database code in my SQLiteOpenhelper is below

p

```
ublic void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String SQL_CREATE_RESTURANTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + ResturantEntry.TABLE_NAME + "("`enter code here`
                + ResturantEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                + ResturantEntry.COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + ResturantEntry.COLUMN_TYPE + " TEXT,"
                + ResturantEntry.COLUMN_ADDRESS + " TEXT,"
                + ResturantEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION + " TEXT,"
                + ResturantEntry.COLUMN_GPSCOORDINATES + " INTEGER,"
                + ResturantEntry.COLUMN_TELEPHONE + " INTEGER,"
                + ResturantEntry.COLUMN_OPENINGHOURS + " INTEGER,"
                + ResturantEntry.COLUMN_CLOSINGHOURS + " INTEGER,"
                + ResturantEntry.COLUMN_CHECKBOX + " TEXT,"
                + ResturantEntry.COLUMN_CHECKBOXVALUE + " TEXT);";


        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_RESTURANTS_TABLE);


    }
```

i keep getting the error in my logcat below

```
#################################################################
    Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
    Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
        (no such column: COLUMN_CHECKBOX (code 1): , while compiling: UPDATE Resturant SET COLUMN_CHECKBOX = '1' WHERE COLUMN_LOCATION = 'Ajah')
    #################################################################
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try have updated the code with the SQLiteDatabase  update method:-

```
public int insert_checkbox(String Str1, String chkboxValue)
 { 
  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase(); 
  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues(); 
  contentValues.put(COLUMN_CHECKBOX, Str1 ); 
  String selection = ResturantEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION + " =? ";

  String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{chkboxValue};
 //count denotes the number of rows update 
 int count =   db.update(ResturantEntry.TABLE_NAME,   contentValues,selection  ,selectionArgs ); 
 retun count;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I finally got it working, many thanks mTak,laalto and Kaveri. your inputs set me off in the right direction and the functionality is working perfectly now. this is my code;

Comment: public int insert_checkbox(String Str1, String chkboxValue ){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(ResturantEntry.COLUMN_CHECKBOX, Str1 );
    String[] whereArgs={chkboxValue};
    int count=db.update(ResturantEntry.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, ResturantEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION+" =? ", whereArgs);

    return count;

}

Answer (score 0):

`COLUMN_CHECKBOX` is a variable name containing a column name and not a literal column name. You should not put it in double quotes in your SQL. Same issue with `COLUMN_LOCATION`.

However, instead of correcting the SQL in `execSQL()`, you would be better off by using `SQLiteDatabase` `update()` method with `ContentValues`. It would also handle things like SQL injection protection for you.

Comment: got it, many thanks for the quick response. Let me give this a shot. regards

Comment: i have tried to use the update() method with ContentValues as you and mTak below have suggested and this is my code.

Comment: public void insert_checkbox(String Str1, String chkboxValue){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COLUMN_CHECKBOX, Str1 );
      
       db.update(ResturantEntry.TABLE_NAME, contentValues, ResturantEntry.COLUMN_LOCATION = chkboxValue,null);
  
        this.getWritableDatabase().insertOrThrow(ResturantContract.ResturantEntry.TABLE_NAME,"",contentValues);
        
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

1. When you want to update a row in db you need to filter (by using it in the `WHERE` clause) by the primary key `ResturantEntry._ID` of the row and then execute the update. You don't seem to have that.
2. You're mixing 2 different methods for updating: `ContentValues` and direct `UPDATE` statement. You don't need both of them, choose one.

Comment: to your first question, no I dont have that as i need to filter by location based on the checkbox location selected by the users. and then update the table to only those locations selected